# Dynamically replacing the fragment of a viewpager with another fragment

Tags: android

I'm using a ViewPager which has 6 fragments(i.e) 6 pages, i want to replace a fragment with a new fragment dynamically.. i'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and overriding getItemPosition method 
the following is the code inside the getItemPosition  method.

```
                 Fragment myFragment  = (Fragment)object;
              FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment iviteFragment = new InviteFragment();
        trans.detach(myFragment);
        trans.add(mPager.getId(), iviteFragment);
                    trans.commit();
        return POSITION_NONE;
```

this doesn't work.